# DocumentBuilder.parse () -- Permission denied

Tags: java, android, rss, xml-parsing, android-2.2-froyo

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance ();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder ();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse ("http://feeds.feedburner.com/d0od?format=xml");
doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
```

For some reason, at the third line, Android always seems to throw a "Permission denied" exception. Can anyone tell me why, and what I'm doing wrong?

---

Using API Level 8 (Froyo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add android.permission.INTERNET to your Manifest. This will let your application to access internet.

Comment: Why are you saying the exact same thing as the above answer?

Comment: 2tolgap: I believe we posted at the same time. I didn't see your answer when I was writing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access the internet (parsing) from your `onCreate()` or the UI thread? You should implement [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) in your `onCreate()` or just move it to a worker thread.

Also, first make sure your Manifest has the correct permission for internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing that URL in your web browser?  Are you able to connect to it?

That exception is fairly self-explanatory.  Your connection does not have the appropriate permissions to access that URL.  Try accessing it manually to confirm.

You can also receive this error if your Android's security software or web filtering settings deem that URL unsafe.  If this is the case, you will need to modify those settings to establish a connection successfully.